# MKAnnotationView.image is not reflected

Tags: objective-c, mapkit, mkannotationview

I'd like to set an image to MKAnnotationView.
But the image is not reflected. It is normal red pin.

ViewController.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "CustomAnnotation.h"
@interface ViewController ()<MKMapViewDelegate>
@end
@implementation ViewController{
    MKMapView* _mapView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    CustomAnnotation* annotation = [[CustomAnnotation alloc]init];
    annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.6699877, 139.7000456);
    annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation.png"];
    [_mapView addAnnotations:@[annotation]];
}
```

CustomAnnotation.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface CustomAnnotation : MKAnnotationView
@property (readwrite, nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
@end
```

CustomAnnotation.m

```
#import "CustomAnnotation.h"
@implementation CustomAnnotation
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a custom image, you have to create and return an `MKAnnotationView` in the map view's `viewForAnnotation` *delegate* method.

If you don't implement that delegate method, the map view will display a default red pin for the annotations you add (regardless of what class  the annotations are).

Here's an example of how you could implement it:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    if (! [annotation isKindOfClass:[CustomAnnotation class]])
    {
        //if this annotation is not a CustomAnnotation
        //(eg. user location blue dot),
        //return nil so the map view draws its default view for it...
        return nil;
    }

    static NSString *reuseId = @"ann";
    MKAnnotationView *av = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (av == nil)
    {
        av = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        av.canShowCallout = YES;
        av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        av.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return av;
}
```

Be sure to set the map view's `delegate` property either in code or connect the outlet in the storyboard/xib.  If the `delegate` is not set, the map view won't call the `viewForAnnotation` method even if you've implemented it and you'll still get the default red pin.

The `addAnnotation` and `addAnnotations` methods are only asking for the annotation *model* objects (objects that implement the `MKAnnotation` protocol which mainly consists of the `coordinate` property).

The *views* for those annotation *model* objects must be returned in the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

Even though your `CustomAnnotation` class doesn't explicitly declare that it conforms to `MKAnnotation`, it implements a `coordinate` property, so the map view is able to show it on the map.

The fact that it happens to also be a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` is something the map view doesn't care about or use from the annotation *model* object.

Your annotation model object should not be a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` as it will just lead to confusion.  It should just implement the `MKAnnotation` protocol so it should be a subclass of `NSObject<MKAnnotation>` (or some other custom class besides `NSObject`).

Change the `CustomAnnotation` interface to:

```
@interface CustomAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation>
```

Change the `title` property from `strong` to `copy` to match the `MKAnnotation` protocol:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, copy) NSString* title;
```

Since `CustomAnnotation` is no longer an `MKAnnotationView`, remove the `image =` line from `viewDidLoad` and be sure to set the annotation's `title` otherwise the callout won't show when you tap on it:

```
//annotation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotation.png"];
annotation.title = @"annotation";
```